# active navbar button when is clicked using jquery and cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put active a navbar button when it's clicked,  but I can't have a correct solution.  I have this:

```
var cookieValue=$.cookie("nav");

$('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function() {
    $.removeCookie("nav");
    $.cookie("nav", $('a',this).attr("id"), { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    var cookieValue = $.cookie("nav");
});
if(cookieValue)
{
    $('#' + cookieValue).addClass('active');
}
```

where cookieValue is the ID of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Hy. maybe it's because you put the if statement outside the click event.

**try something like this:**

```
var cookieValue=$.cookie("nav");

$('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function() {
    $.removeCookie("nav");
    $.cookie("nav", $('a',this).attr("id"), { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    var cookieValue = $.cookie("nav");

if(cookieValue)
{
    $('#' + cookieValue).addClass('active');
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
    var cookieValue=$.cookie("nav");

    $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function() {
        $.removeCookie("nav");
        $.cookie("nav", $('a',this).attr("id"), { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        var cookieValue = $.cookie("nav");
    });
    if(cookieValue)

{
    $('#' + cookieValue).removeClass('active');
    $('#' + cookieValue).parent().addClass('active');
}
```